# Does PHP self auto-handle path delimiters in Win and *nix?

Tags: php, windows, linux, unix

Does PHP self **auto-handle** path delimiters in Win and *nix?

Ex.: converting **\** to **/** ... or **\** to **\\**?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `auto-handle`?

Comment: Sorry what are you asking? auto-handle?

Comment: Why downvote? Question is valid and not that silly as may look. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But you can use the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant.

[Predefined Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php)

Comment: Yes, i know that. but PHP do not do this(automatic)?

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub I don't think it's PHP. It's probably deeper in the Web Server or OS. I know that using a path like `/srv/www` will work on my windows XAMPP, and map to `C:\srv\www`. I don't know what makes it work. I don't mind because it's only for scripts on debugging. But in productions I would never rely on that if I'm targeting multiple operating systems.

Comment: Why the downvote? Isn't this constant designed explicitly for that purpose?

Comment: PHP uses this contants internally. But if you supply a path to a php function PHP assumes you have supplied correct path.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not fully clear to me but... I'd aswer "yes, but". "Yes" as your script can do i.e. `include "foo/bar/smth.php";` and it will work the same on windows and linux/unix PHPs and you do not need to bother (however if you do `include "foo\bar\smth.php";` then it may work on windows (never checked) but will not work on linux/unix, so beware). So filesystem access layer is aware about this and would take care. And "but", becasue  if you are also talking about i.e. doing http access (i.e. over HTTP) then "No" as it got nothing do with PHP. Also, I recall some MSIE did convert backslashes for normal slashes, so crap like `htt:\\` works, but that's example of extremely wrong approach.

Comment: PHP does'nt do this. Windows doing this(supports as both).

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub so you say that if I compile C program that does `fopen("C:/windows/fonts/trebuchet.ttf", "rb");` it will work? I am unable to test that myself at the moment, but I am yet not convinced it is true. Can you back your claims with any i.e. MSDN docs or so?